# Webpack suppress eslint warnings on browser console

Tags: node.js, webpack, eslint

I`ve finished configuring my eslint rules and refactoring project files according to my rules. Thing is that I have some warnings that I may want to leave there for a while. But my problem is that warnings are being shown on browser console, what makes development impossible.

[image]

Below, my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const context = path.resolve('.');


module.exports = {
  context: context,
  entry: './src/client.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(context, 'build/client'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
    ],
    loaders: [{
      test: /(?:node_modules).+\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader',
        'sass-resources'
      ])
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    }, {
     test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
   }, {
     test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
   }, {
     test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
   }, {
     test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: "file"
   }, {
     test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
     loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
   }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      require('autoprefixer')
    ];
  },
  sassResources: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/stylesheets/base/_variables.scss'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/stylesheets/base/_mixins.scss')
  ],
  devServer: {
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 1000
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name]-[hash].css"),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'local')
    })
  ],
  devtool: "cheap-module-source-map"
};
```

I have no problem with `errors` being displayed on browser console, but is there a way to suppress warnings ONLY on browser console and not on the node terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://devhub.io/repos/coryhouse-eslint-loader

In my webpack.config.js I have options setup:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['es2015', {modules: false}],
              'react'
            ],
            plugins: [ 'react-hot-loader/babel' ]
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          options: {
            quiet: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The last line is `quiet: true`, which is how it suppresses the warnings.

Comment: This also hides the warnings on the node terminal, not just on the browser console

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to have the logs in the terminal but not in the browser.

Answer (score 6):

Use

*clientLogLevel: "none"*

in the devServer config

Doc: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverclientloglevel

> ### `devServer.clientLogLevel`
>
> `string: 'none' | 'info' | 'error' | 'warning'`
>
> When using inline mode, the console in your DevTools will show you messages e.g. before reloading, before an error or when [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) is enabled. Defaults to `info`.
>
> `devServer.clientLogLevel` may be too verbose, you can turn logging off by setting it to `'none'`.
>
> #### `webpack.config.js`
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   //...
>   devServer: {
>     clientLogLevel: 'none'
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> Usage via the CLI
>
> ```
> webpack-dev-server --client-log-level none
> ```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.